# Flask Sock (Websocket) route runs one last time before disconnect

Tags: python, flask, websocket

In `flask-sock` which is for regular websockets, If I run a `while` loop in a route function, and at the end use a `time.sleep(15)`, if I disconnect during the `time.sleep` the loop will run for one last time before disconnecting.

I tried to use try except with a boolean to disable the loop but it won't stop it. Any ideas?

```
@socket.route('/example')
def example(websocket):
    while True:
        print('RAN')

        time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve why it runs twice if terminated during the sleep function, but an alternative route is to ask again if it needs to be run, thus ensuring the connection is still alive.

```
@socket.route('/example')
def example(websocket):
    while True:
        websocket.send("Need?")
        need = websocket.receive()
            
        if need == 'true':
            print('RAN')

        time.sleep(10)
```